# Way to indicate number of iterations in BGL

Tags: c++, progress, boost-graph

I'm writing an C++ application that uses boost graph library.
I use `kruskal_minimum_spanning_tree` function in BGL.
Are there any ways to check how many times does this function iterate, because application hangs at this function?

Update. I have a progress bar in application that indicates progress of some algorithm. When I pass 100 vertices to BGL, it computes minimum spanning tree for less than a second. But when I pass more than 10000 vertices, BGL can calculate the tree for 10 or even 20 minutes. So I would like to see, how much edges in tree are computed.

Comment: If it hangs, you can debug it. But best to check the preconditions from the documentation(s) (are weights (required to be) positive?)

Comment: Weights are always positive.